# Filter out RSS items with description less than 3 characters using Yahoo Pipes

Tags: regex, filter, rss, yahoo-pipes

I am trying to filter out items that has empty description or description shorter than 3 characters using this Yahoo Pipe:
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=966d5a5006cad6b2825d4f744b1ebb50#eefd469cf1c28d4d6cb6bd6c6c1ab6b8

Here is the workflow of the Pipe:

"Fetch Feed" module - fetch the feeds
"Create RSS" module - create new Feed and use item description as item title for new feed
"Regex" module – remove html tags from title
"Filter" module – I want to block items that have either empty descriptions or descriptions shorter than 3 characters, I am not sure what to put there – "null", "*"…?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your filter to **permit** items that match rather than block, and change your regex to the following:

`^.{3,}$`

Comment: OK,I changed it http://screencast.com/t/sGIhgYoK5 but it seem like those items are still passing through

Comment: @user1833760 I think the problem here is you are trying to filter on description in your pipe, but you are showing examples of the title in the screenshot. What I would do is move the regex filter to directly below your fetch feed and change it to "permit" on "item.title" rather than description and use ^.{3,}$ as your regex. See http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=4a288825eb82b11648c8b134ee562eb1